# Access Front-end to MySql: Forms won't add or update records

Tags: mysql, forms, ms-access, dao, adodb

I have a problem using an Access Application connected to a MySql Database.
I test UPDATE on one small table with a VBA procedure, using DAO

```
UPDATE tblFormateur 
SET Prenom = 'Werner' 
WHERE Nom='HEISENBERG' "
```

The first time I run the query, it's ok.
But if I run the same query, without changing the value,(keeping Prenom = 'Werner')
I get an error message saying that the query has not been executed,
due to a lock violation.
If I run the query again, but with a different value, e.g Prenom = 'Peter',
the query is executed without error.

On the other hand, If I do the same experiment with ADODB,
I do not get any error.

One can say: let's go with ADODB!

The problem is that the Access application Forms use DAO, not ADODB!
So all the forms won't be able to either add new records or update records.

Did you experienced the same issue?
Are there some parameters of the ODBC driver that needs to be set?

Thank's advance for any help.

Windows 11
Access Office 365
ODBC connector 8.0 CE

Answer (score 0):

If you have a linked table as form `RecordSource` and you run an update query, it always give you this error.
The error appears because Access do not detect any changes. If you have a field with value 'Test' and than you delete this value, rewrite 'Test', Access doesn't detect any changes because the value is the same.

To bypass this error you can make a random field that add n + 1 before running your query. When you open the form, field is set to 0, before you run the query is 1, next time is 2 and so on.

Access will detect changes to the form and won't give you this error.